# Serialization using BinaryFormater - C#

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I am trying to serialize and deserialize my game's save with BinaryFormatter.
I am using this utility method, so I don't have to use the ISerializable interface and write AddValue() manually for each field to support versioning.

```
public void Serialize(object obj, string path)
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldsPublic = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    FieldInfo[] fieldsPrivate = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (FieldInfo info in fieldsPublic)
    {
        object valiue = info.GetValue(obj);
        if(!info.IsDefined(typeof(NonSerializedAttribute), true))
            fields.Add(info, info.GetValue(obj));
    }
    foreach (FieldInfo info in fieldsPrivate)
    {
        if (info.IsDefined(typeof(SerializeField), true))
            fields.Add(info, info.GetValue(obj));
    }
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(path);

    bf.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
    bf.Serialize(file, fields);

    file.Close();
}
```

Now, the problem is that when serializing this way, the fields inside fieldsPublic include only public members. I also want to include the private members that have [SerializeField] Attribute. But this attribute is ignored since it checks fields with this attribute only on the first level of the object.

Example, when I serialize class A object:

```
class A
{
     public B b;
     [SerializeField] 
     private int value; // This is NOT ignored
}

class B
{
     [SerializeField] 
     private int value; // This is ignored
}
```

How can I also make it serialize private variables having the [SerializeField] field attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: "to support versioning", well, do you suspect you will have a versioning issue in the future? Binary serialization is meant to be used as a *transport* mechanism, between different applications (of the same version) or different appdomains, or similar. It is **not** meant as a *storage mechanism*.

Comment: Why don't you simply stick the `[Serializable]` attribute on the class and rely on the default behavior? By the way, BinaryFormatter is one of the worst serialization methods, I strongly suggest you to try something else if you want to avoid versioning issues.

Comment: BinaryFormatter does not serialize private fields. Your efforts to map the private members from A does not also extend into mapping the private members of the B therein. What you're trying to do is prone to issues commonly experienced with deep copy. You're doing it the hard way.

Comment: I suppose you discovered that it is not that simple to write your own serializer.  You have to do all the work that BinaryFormatter is doing.  A type is internally structured like a tree.  When you find a field of a non-POD field type back then you should *not* add it to fields, you have to recurse and in turn look at the fields of that non-POD type.  Well, that is not simple to get right at all.  Keep it simple and only use the [NonSerialized] attribute.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Why is not binary formatter meant for storage? I am storing their entire play world and game state. It keeps all references after deserialization. Also by versioning I mean that when I remove or add field into the serialized class in the future, it wont crash when deserializing the older save where that field is missing.

Comment: It is prone to versioning issues when you compile new versions of your assemblies and refactor things. At some point you might experience that the type names differ because the full names of things, including namespaces and assemblies, are stored in the serialized data. So long-term storage is not advised.

Comment: @Biscuits It seems it can serialize private fields. You just have to put attributes on fields you want have serialize and then check it. You can specifi BindingFlags.NonPublic to include privates.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ah, I know what you mean, when in future I change class name from Car to CarClass, it will break. Yes I am awake of that, but Im not sure how to avoid this even with other types of storage systems. And I cannot use XML as storage format since it can be read and changed easily (e.g. user can cheat)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What would you use for serializing your data then?

Comment: I typically set up a database or use json, in some cases I have used protocol buffers.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah, I am talking about game development. All games that do not have multiplayer do not use any database. Json is readable, so many devs wont use it. And I guess protocol buffers does also require networking.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

The serializer is working correctly now. As far as solution goes, problem was with deserialization, where I was deserializing only public fields, which ignored the private ones....

The versioning I had in mind was about adding or removing fields, so it doesnt crash when loading game with older save. 
But this is also handled with the serializer.